# How to combine two of three stacked line graphs using facet_grid in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

Using the below data and code I produce three line graphs stacked upon one another. I want to combine 'Total Breeding Pairs' and 'Total Chicks Banded' into the one graph stacked upon a second graph of only '% Chicks Banded..'

I've done a quick search and have come across cowplot, but it seems to stack it side by side, and I need the x-axis to align for the two plots.

my code:

```
ggplot(data = `meltedInd`, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = variable), size = 1) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("deepskyblue", "firebrick1", "limegreen")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("") + ggtitle("") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020), 
  limits = c(1986,2017)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

A sample of my data:

```
Year     variable              value
1986     Total Breeding Pairs   NA
1987     Total Breeding Pairs  1000
1988     Total Breeding Pairs  2200
1989     Total Breeding Pairs  2150
1986     Total Chicks Banded   484
1987     Total Chicks Banded   551
1988     Total Chicks Banded   1498
1989     Total Chicks Banded   1609
1986  % Chicks Banded per Pair   NA
1987  % Chicks Banded per Pair  55.10
1988  % Chicks Banded per Pair  68.09
1989  % Chicks Banded per Pair  74.84
```

Comment: `plot_grid` from the cowplot package can stack in either direction. You can refer [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html) for some examples.

Comment: I clearly didn't look hard enough at the cowplot package!
Thanks very much your link was perfect, the link I'd seen wasn't as great.
I now have exactly as I'd wanted!